# How do I change the width of custom dialog fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I created a custom dialog fragment but the width is very narrow. How can I increase it? I thought by setting width to `800dp`, the dialog layout would wrap the content, but it constrains it within its default width.

Here is what I am looking for:

[image]

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="800dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/cancel_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cancel"
    android:paddingVertical="@dimen/keyline_6"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
    style="@style/MyTheme.Button.TextButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/terms_condition_header"/>


<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:id="@+id/terms_condition_header"
    android:padding="@dimen/keyline_6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Terms And Conditions"
    android:textColor="@color/color_terms_condition_header"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cancel_btn"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MyTheme.Subtitle1"/>


    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:id="@+id/appCompatTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/keyline_6"
        android:textColor="@color/color_terms_condition_header"
        android:text="WHAT DRIVES US? Changing up your all-day, every-day, fun-day experience and having a good time doing it."
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MyTheme.Subtitle2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/appCompatTextView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/terms_condition_header"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/appCompatTextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingVertical="@dimen/keyline_4"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/keyline_6"
        android:text="Please read, respect and acknowledge the policies listed below:"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MyTheme.Subtitle3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/terms_condition_container"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appCompatTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/terms_condition_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/keyline_6"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appCompatTextView2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <include layout="@layout/terms_condition_text"/>

    </FrameLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/accept_terms_button"
        style="@style/MyTheme.Button.Secondary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/color_secondary"
        android:text="Accept Terms And Conditions"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/terms_condition_container" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Dialog class:

```
class TermsAndConditionDialogFragment : BaseDialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_terms_condition, container, false)


        return view
    }

}
```

My preview:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (getContext() == null) return;
        getDialog().getWindow().setLayout(((int) (0.8 * ScreenUtils.getScreenWidth(getContext()))), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
```

and this for `getScreenWidth`

```
public static int getScreenWidth(Context context) {
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        return dm.widthPixels;
    }
```